# Python BeautifulSoup4 only shows tag but does not show the text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am practicing web scraping using BeautifulSoup4 to scrape data from a website. However, when I run my code, it only shows the opening tag and ending tag when there is clearly a text between them when I do inspect element on the website.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://emenscr.nesdc.go.th/thaime/loanact/view.html?id=43k11nkm0VFwVVOZxlX9'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(r,'lxml')

p_name = soup.find('span', id='viewer_loanact_group')
print(p_name)
```

Output:

```
In [54]: runcell(0, 'D:/computer_vision_project/bpm/untitled3.py')
<span id="viewer_loanact_group"></span>
```

The html:

```
<tr>                                                               
<th>กลุ่มของข้อเสนอโครงการ</th>
 <td>
  <span id="viewer_loanact_group">ข้อเสนอระดับโครงการย่อยที่มีวัตถุประสงค์เพื่อฟื้นฟูเศรษฐกิจและสังคม ตามบัญชีแนบท้าย พ.ร.ก. เงินกู้ฯ (กลุ่มที่ 3)
  </span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `print(p_name.text)`

Comment: @QHarr that just makes the code return nothing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chromedriver download link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**unzip and copy the .exe file to a folder

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = "**path of the folder/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)


url = 'https://emenscr.nesdc.go.th/thaime/loanact/view.html?id=43k11nkm0VFwVVOZxlX9'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
p_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="viewer_loanact_group"]')
print(p_name.text)
```